# How will I make a pendrive write protected?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, make, write-protect

I just want to make my **pendrive** **write protected** just to make sure, when I insert it public PCs like in cyber cafes in order to just read the files, it doesn't get virus affected. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (deep breath) http://superuser.com/questions/184004/make-a-usb-drive-read-only OR http://superuser.com/questions/458749/can-you-make-a-flashdrive-read-only OR http://superuser.com/questions/543067/why-is-my-usb-flash-drive-now-read-only

Comment: other info here http://superuser.com/questions/391397/pen-drive-automatically-got-write-protected?rq=1 & http://superuser.com/questions/269600/how-to-write-protect-a-usb-key  Add it all up it is easiest to get a pendrive with protect switch, or get SD card (with protect) and reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your USB drive has a physical switch, **this is not possible**. You cannot enforce something like this using a software solution, especially when you do not control the system.

Comment: ...or your hardware pen has to be projected  to have only authorized access, that means that there is a microprocessor inside with a _"nano operative system"_ that asks for authentication and only after allow to read and write. So not a normal pen drive.

Comment: There are some low-level manufacturer tools that can enable/disable a write lock on a drive - though the whole security of this system is based on the fact that these tools are not publicly available and there are no standards regarding such mechanisms (otherwise - anybody could unlock that etc.). So you could order read-only flash memory with some files written in china - or try to get a manufacturer tool for your exact model of memory - but I don't think that's going to be easy ;)

Answer (score 13):

You could always try locking the drive using [diskpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart).

Open CMD as admin and type `diskpart`.

When diskpart loads - type `list disk`

This will give you a list of drives in your machine.

Select your USB device using the `select disk 1` command (where 1 is the number of your USB)

Use `attributes disk set readonly` to set the drive as read only.

Comment: The above method will set readonly USB disk only on PC that has executed diskpart.

Answer (score 4):

If your stick uses the NTFS filesystem, you can do the following. If not, consider copying the files off of the drive, then format as NTFS.

Do the following:

1. Open your explorer and select the driveletter of your USB drive.\
2. Right click and select `Properties`
3. Open the tab Security
4. Click the `Change` button, and answer yes to the UAC prompt if applicable.
5. Look if there's an Everyone user. It is likely not there. If it is, skip step 8.
6. Click on <kbd>Add...</kbd>
7. Type in `Everyone` and click <kbd>Ok</kbd>
8. Select the Everyone user
9. Set a checkmark in the column `deny` for Write.

From this moment on, no one can change the drive anymore. If you want to make changes, Repeat the above steps and remove the checkbox for write in the `deny` column.

Although the screenshot is dutch, it is showing the endresult.

[image]

Comment: this method requires NTFS file system

Comment: @msoa made an edit to this very old answer. :)