# Is there any way to prevent a USB flash drive from being written to?

Tags: usb, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, virus, malware

I see lots of articles about preventing a specific computer from writing to a USB flash drive or preventing malware from getting from a USB flash drive to a computer; what I can’t find anything for is how to prevent any system from writing to a USB flash drive.

I work at an I.T. help desk and as such I work with some devices that have some form of malware. From simple adware, to more advanced kinds of infections it varies. I have a USB flash drive with a bunch of tools I use day to day to fix some of the more common issues. I want to lock this USB flash drive down and prevent it from being modified. I know some viruses will try to infect a USB device, and this is exactly what I want to avoid. I don’t want to use a USB flash drive on one users computer and then plug it into the next ones and infect them.

Is there an effective method—that is OS independent—to prevent a USB flash drive from being written to? I could use a disc to do this, and use a USB powered disc drive where optical drives are not present in the laptop, however this is not as convenient of a method, so I’d prefer to use a USB flash drive if possible.

Comment: this [question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/how-reliable-is-a-write-protection-switch-on-a-usb-flash-drive) on security.stackexchange seems related

Comment: Also *[How will I make a pendrive write protected?](http://superuser.com/questions/769299)*

Comment: Everyone is clueless... this can be done with the oem tools leaked all over the internet...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there an effective method that is OS independent to prevent a USB
>   from being written to?

Not really unless you are using a device that *explicitly* uses a forensic write blocker/controller or something similar that blocks data writes on a controller level.

Read and write permissions/restrictions on the vast majority of devices out there are inherently, physically read and write capable—like USB flash drives—is a *logical* OS-based construct. When something gains malicious access to a device, it simply doesn’t care about such circumventable logical restrictions. Remember: Code—such as viruses and malware—that can infect a system will basically operate on “root”/“admin” level at all times and can just do whatever it wants.

So even those SD cards that have those little write-protect switches are fairly useless since anything that gains deep system access can just ignore that “don’t write to me” setting. For example, [look over this list of various ways to disable/circumvent write protection to SD cards](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Write-Protection) on various systems; a simple adjustment to registry settings for `StorageDevicePolicies` from `1` to `0` in Windows will essentially tell the system to ignore the write-protect switch.

This kind of “hack” is no deep secret and even openly discussed/advocated by Microsoft support—such as in [this official support thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-flash-drive-prompts-with-write-protected/2012d40c-7d90-4967-b2c2-2d67c08561e2)—when providing support to users who have legitimate reasons to bypass write protection on USB devices.

Your best bet—if preventing unauthorized write access is a goal—is to use media that *physically* blocks write access like CD-R’s or DVD-R’s after they are burned.

> I could use a disc to do this, and use a USB powered disc drive where
>   optical drives are not present in the laptop, however this is not as
>   convenient of a method, so I’d prefer to use a USB flash drive if possible.

Honestly, the use of truly read only media—like a burned CD-R or DVD-R—is the only simple and practical way to ensure malicious writing access is stopped at a deeper level. It might seem inconvenient, but the way I would approach this is simple:

- **CD-R/DVD-R Master of Tools:** Create a CD-R/DVD-R with all the tools on need on it. Use that as the master. Maybe burn a few copies to have as backups.
- **Create a USB version of the CD-R/DVD-R Master:** Now with that CD-R/DVD-R created, create an exact clone of the contents of that CD-R/DVD-R on a USB flash drive. The logic being that you can use this USB flash drive daily and if somehow it chokes or gets infected, you can then “downgrade” to the CD-R/DVD-R.

Now all that said, *there is* such a thing as a [forensic write blocker/controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_disk_controller). These devices mainly provide an interface between a SATA or IDE drive and a USB connection that will allow one to mount and access a SATA or IDE drive without risk of data being written to it. And as the term “forensics” implies, these devices are mainly intended for legal and/or law enforcement purposes to ensure that a device in a “chain of custody” cannot be tampered with.

So if a “bad guy” is arrested, law enforcement might take their laptop, remove the hard drive and connect it to a forensic write blocker/controller to gather evidence for whatever purpose they need in a way that assures the courts and others that the data was not tampered with.

That said, these forensic write blocker/controller devices are not cheap—they run around $200 to $300 (U.S. dollars)—and mainly have interfaces that are USB to SATA or IDE; not USB to USB. But wait! I was able to find [this “ToughTech m3” enclosure](http://www.cru-inc.com/products/toughtech/toughtech-m3/) that claims to have a “Unique WriteProtect read-only mode”:

> It features a unique WriteProtect read-only mode that "locks down"
>   your data and prevents someone from accidentally deleting or modifying
>   it. This is a handy way to protect your drive when loaning it to a
>   client or someone else to distribute files or data.

A [quick search online](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ToughTech%20m3%20enclosure&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) shows that this enclosure can be had for less than $50 (U.S. dollars). And if it does what it claims—in the same manner a forensic write blocker/controller works—then this could be a good investment for someone like you. But I have no direct experience with this device so I cannot speak for it’s true ability to protect data from inadvertent/accidental/unauthorized write access.

Comment: And is there an effective method to determine if a USB flash drive has been infected?

Comment: Okay sounds good! Thanks for the help. Since the USB drive doesn't contain much on it, would it be a bad idea to just reformat the drive after every use? Essentially just have an "image" for the usb?

Comment: 'those SD cards that have those little write-protect switches are fairly useless since anything that gains deep system access can just ignore that “don’t write to me” setting' -- Can you provide me a link that backs this claim?

Comment: Okay sounds good. If it has a physical write protection switch, isn't this preventing it at a level in which the computer actually can not alter? Like I mean it just doesn't seem like it would be physically possible to mess with that from a software level.

Comment: More than that, the physical switch on most SD cards isn't electrically connected to anything. It's literally a little piece of plastic that the hardware can *optionally* detect and respond to, often with an optical sensor. Some readers don't have that sensor (e.g. the lock detection of the reader on a Raspberry Pi [isn't connected to anything](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5114/9390) on the PCB side).

Comment: I learn new things everyday, and today it's about the write-protect switch on SD cards...

Comment: @Fogest: What about a checksum as a way to detect infection? If you have a reliable, uninfected base system a checksum ought to be a pretty reliable way to know if or not anything on your USB flash drive got changed by the infected system it was inserted into. Not sure but that's why I think. Maybe a `sha` or an `md5sum`

Comment: @Fogest It wouldn't be a bad idea to reformat and re-image after every use except that humans forget! Once in a while you'll absent mindedly forget to re-image and then you have a disaster.

Comment: @JakeGould Yes, there is a USB-to-USB one, I have seen a pic once, and a sales page on a site, but I can't remember the name and after 5 pages of google searches I gave up :/

Answer (score 11):

> Is there an effective method—that is OS independent—to prevent a USB flash drive from being written to ?

Yes, there are a few.

- You can use a **forensic USB write blocker** such as [this one](http://www.cru-inc.com/products/wiebetech/usb_writeblocker/):

[image]

From the product description:

> The compact USB WriteBlocker connects to USB storage devices and protects their contents during an investigation. To use, simply connect the WriteBlocker to the suspect device.
>
> The USB WriteBlocker connects to most USB storage devices: USB thumb drives, digital cameras, cell phones, or most anything with a USB connection.

- Some USB flash drives have physical write-protection switches (**Important**: Many devices will have "logical" switches that can be bypassed by the software, read [@Giacomo1968's excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/888984/167207) for more in-depth info):

[image]

- Some IDE/SATA-to-USB adapters have write-disable locks:

[image]